# Getting Username with node.js and redirecting (success/failure)

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am getting started with node.js and now I got stuck.

```js
  var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbconfig = require('../config/database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);

  
  
  
  app.get('/createarticle', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    res.render('createarticle.ejs', {
      user:req.user
    });
   });
   
   app.post('/createarticle' , (req, res ) => {

    let sql = 'INSERT INTO news SET ?'
    let post = {
       // author: req.user.username,
        content : req.body.content,
        title: req.body.title
    }
    connection.query(sql, post, (err, res) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('success');
        console.log(res);
       
        
    });
    
});
```

If I use req.user.username I get this error message Cannot read property 'username' of undefined.
I also tried user.username and req.user.

In my main JS I have this function that shoud always give the user if logged in.

```js
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
     next();
    });
```

In addition to this I want to include two redirects but I don't know where to put it.

successRedirect: '/',
 failureRedirect: '/createarticle',

I appreciate every answer and pacience with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I have to post an answer:

What does your request object look like:

```js
  app.get('/createarticle', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    console.log('request',req)
    res.render('createarticle.ejs', {
      user:req.user
    });
   });
```

If you're not populating the request object in your 'GET' from your front end,
you won't have the user you are asking for.

You may want to do some handling in the front to make sure that you only send populated request objects.

Comment: I solved the problem, my mistaka was in the Mysql table, I somehow declared the column author as an integer... but I am still having problems to redirect after succesfully inserting data. I am getting the error res.redirect is not a function..

Comment: check for typos and make sure you are defining the parameters in the right* order ```function(req, res){etc...}```

Comment: also solved this, the problem was that I was overriding the res with another variable.. thank you for your help